# Error when I send email of Marketing cloud in salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

when I send a email of Marketing cloud in salesforce when I preview email I got a error 'Error retrieving subscriber data: [E131] We couldn't retrieve the Contact/Lead information for the Marketing Cloud. Make sure you have permission to access email opt out and try again'

pls suggest me if there is any solution for that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your user has the needed permission sets for Marketing Cloud Connect applied, as well as having the Sales/Service Cloud User integrated with a Marketing Cloud user with the correct permissions. Field level security settings on the Contact/Lead object's opt out field could also have an impact on the email send.

If that doesn't help there may be a problem with the API user integration.

**Possible reasons summarized:**

- Necessary permission sets not applied
- Sales/Service Cloud user not integrated with Marketing Cloud user
- Field level security not set correctly
- API user integration faulty

**Related information:**

- [Manage Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_manage_users.htm&type=5)
- [Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_troubleshooting_guide.htm&type=5)
- [Troubleshoot Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_troubleshoot_connected_app.htm&type=5)
- [Update Field Level Security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_update_field_level_security.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

This has happened more than one - I upload a new journey / email - and when i go to send it i can preview - but i can't edit - instead i get an angry red:

An error occurred while rendering the email preview. Ask your Marketing Cloud admin to check the connected journey.

What am i doing wrong???